# Reformatting downloaded Excel data

Tags: r, excel, date, formatting

I have downloaded some GDP data in .xls-format from the OECD website. However, to make this data workable in R, I need to reformat the data to a .csv file. More specifically, I need the year, day and month in the first column, and after the comma I need the GDP values (for example: 1990-01-01, 234590).

The column with GDP values can be easily copied and transposed, but how does one quickly add dates? Is there a fast way to do this, without having to add in the dates manually?

[image: Example output]

Thanks for the help!

Best,
Sean

PS. Link to (one of) the specific OECD files: https://ufile.io/8ogav or https://stats.oecd.org/index.aspx?queryid=350#

PSS. I have now changed the file to this:

[image: Example 2]

Which I would like to transform into the same style as example 1. 
Codes that I use for reading in data:

```
gdp.start <- c(1970,1) # type "double"
gdp.end   <- c(2018,1)

gdp.raw <- "rawData/germany_gdp.csv"
gdp.table <- read.table(gdp.raw, skip = 1, header = F, sep = ',', stringsAsFactors = F)
gdp.ger <- ts(gdp.table[,2], start = gdp.start, frequency = 4) # time-series representation
```

PSS.

```
dput(head(gdp.table))
structure(list(V1 = c("Q2-1970;1.438.810 ", "Q3-1970;1.465.684 ", 
"Q4-1970;1.478.108 ", "Q1-1971;1.449.712 ", "Q2-1971;1.480.136 ", 
"Q3-1971;1.505.743 ")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you give some sample input data with `dput()`?

Comment: Why do you have to convert the file before reading it into R?  There are plenty of options for reading XLS and XLSX files. For example the packages: `readxl` (part of `tidyverse`) and `openxlsx`

Comment: The OECD website has an option to download in CSV format.

Comment: I agree with all these statements, but the data never comes in the form as in 'Example output'.

Comment: A link to the specific files on OECD might help others provide an answer

Comment: I have added an upload link or the real link, which needs some adjusting before you can download the table

Comment: Where are you getting the GDP values? I just went to you link, clicked "Text file (CSV)", and looked at the file, and the only variant number-like field is `$Value`, which ranges from -41.3 to +97.8. (The XLS export generated XML, so was effectively useless for me.)

Comment: If this question is not about reading in data from a CSV, I suggest you [reduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to remove working stuff. For instance (as @bk18 suggested), just give us `dput(head(gdp.raw))` and remove any code and discussion about CSV or XLS. It seems to me this problem is only about translating `"1975-Q3"` to `"1975-07-01"` (date object), and subsetting your data into just two columns.

Comment: @r2evans That is correct. Well, let me follow your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your data:

```
z <- structure(list(V1 = c("Q2-1970;1.438.810 ", "Q3-1970;1.465.684 ", 
"Q4-1970;1.478.108 ", "Q1-1971;1.449.712 ", "Q2-1971;1.480.136 ", 
"Q3-1971;1.505.743 ")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
dat <- read.csv2(text=paste(z$V1, collapse='\n'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=FALSE)
dat
#        V1         V2
# 1 Q2-1970 1.438.810 
# 2 Q3-1970 1.465.684 
# 3 Q4-1970 1.478.108 
# 4 Q1-1971 1.449.712 
# 5 Q2-1971 1.480.136 
# 6 Q3-1971 1.505.743
```

and a simple function to replace quarters with the first date of each quarter

```
quarters <- function(s, format) {
  qs <- c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4")
  dts <- c("01-01", "04-01", "07-01", "10-01")
  for (i in seq_along(qs))
    s <- sub(qs[i], dts[i], s)
  if (! missing(format))
    s <- as.Date(s, format=format)
  s
}
```

We can change them into strings of dates, preserving the order:

```
str(quarters(dat$V1))
#  chr [1:6] "04-01-1970" "07-01-1970" "10-01-1970" "01-01-1971" ...
```

or we can convert into `Date` objects by setting the format:

```
str( quarters(dat$V1, format='%m-%d-%Y') )
#  Date[1:6], format: "1970-04-01" "1970-07-01" "1970-10-01" "1971-01-01" ...
```

so replacing the column with the actual `Date` object is simply `dat$V1 <- quarters(dat$V1, format='%m-%d-%Y')`.

Comment: This is amazing! Please let me try to implement this!

Comment: Could you be a little more clear on how to achieve 1970-04-01, 1970-07-01, etc. ?

Comment: And there is one more issue, the numbers when imported are rounded and are notated as 1.438.810, 1.464.684, etc. While in the original file the value is notated as 1438809.708139, I would like to preserve this original notation. Do you possibly know how to do this?

Comment: The `quarters` function does it: it replaces `"Q1"` in the `$V1` column with `"01-01"`; replaces `"Q2"` with `"04-01"`; etc. From that, `"Q2-1970"` is translated into `"04-01-1970"`, which we then turn into a `Date` object with `as.Date("04-01-1970",format="%m-%d-%Y")`.

Comment: As to your issue with `1.438.810`, that's completely on you: I used the data as you gave it in your question. I still have no idea where you get that data, it was not in the exported data I saw when I visited the site once. I do not attempt to deal with it here since it does not affect handling quarters-to-dates.

Comment: Clear. However, the quarters function is giving me all NA rows